# Python: Pass inequality as string in dict for evaluation

Tags: python, function, sign, inequality

I need to pass inequalities to a function for evaluation within the function. Is there a way to evaluation the inequality if passed as a string? Or must I pass a representation of the inequality and use if/else statements to generate the sign?

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluating the inequality"?  Could you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but it sounds like you want to evaluate a string containing an expression (such as `x > 5`). Rather than doing that, which is unnecessarily complex, and potentially a security hazard, just define a function, either in the conventional way or using lambda.

```
def gt5(x):
    return x > 5
```

or

```
gt5 = lambda x: x > 5
```

These are both equivalent; now you can pass around `gt5` however you like, and when the time comes, you simply call it

```
y = 6
if gt5(y):
    ...
```

As [Gerrat's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913167/python-pass-inequality-as-string-in-dict-for-evaluation/6913237#6913237) answer suggests, the [operator](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module may also be useful for things like this.

---

Now that I know you are processing user strings, I would definitely suggest creating a dictionary that maps strings to functions. (Perhaps that's what you meant in your title?) Passing userland strings into `getattr` seems bad in a number of ways. What happens if you want to add a string that doesn't correspond to an attribute of `operator`? What happens if the user passes in a string corresponding to a private attribute? Better to create a custom dictionary mapping strings to functions. A dict allows you to specify just those strings you want to accept.

```
func_dict = {
    'lt'   : operator.lt,
    'gt'   : operator.gt,
    'nand' : lambda x, y: not (x and y)
}
```

You could still save yourself work by using `getattr` + `operator` to build the dict from a list of strings that you want to accept. Something like:

```
func_dict = dict((s, getattr(operator, s)) for s in ['lt', 'gt'])
```

Then update `func_dict` like so:

```
custom_dict = {
    'nand' : lambda x, y: not (x and y)
}

func_dict.update(custom_dict)
```

From there you can easily call functions in the dict like so:

```
>>> func_dict['lt'](5, 7)
True
```

Comment: this is a good solution. In your suggestion, are you still assuming the user passes a string in the interface that maps to the function on the processing side? i.e. func_dict lives on the processing side?

Comment: @strimp099, well, I'm assuming this is an end-user interface, and not an API or something like that. So given that assumption, yes, `func_dict` lives on the processing side; a user enters a string, and then you pass that string to func_dict to look up the function to execute. (But this could happen as soon as the user passes in the string, or much later -- whatever makes sense in your case.) If this is the interface of a library module or something like that, then there may well be no need to use strings at all; you could accept any function.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `operator` module, and pass the appropriate method on it:

```
import operator

def check(op, a, b)
    return op(a,b)

op = operator.ne
check(op, 2,3)


>>> True
```

Comment: I ended up passing a string lt, le, eq, ge, or gt to the function then calling fcn = getattr(operator, 'le') which worked perfectly. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @strimp099: So why are you passing a string in the first place?  Just pass `operator.lt` etc.

Comment: The user at the interface level is passing the argument so I wanted to make it a little cleaner. If there is a speed enhancement I would consider it, I'm testing now. Good idea, thanks.

Comment: @strimp099, using `getattr` + `operator` to process user strings seems brittle. See my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913167/python-pass-inequality-as-string-in-dict-for-evaluation/6913272#6913272).