# How to Evaluate Inequality inside a String in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, eval

I have a text file (an output of a different process that I can't alter) which contains logical comparisons (only these three: `>, <=, in`) stored as strings. Let's say this is a line in my file, which should be evaluated:

```
myStr = "x>2 and y<=30 and z in ('def', 'abc')"
```

Some of my variables are categorical and I specify them, and the rest are numerical:

```
categoricalVars = ('z')
```

The values of my variables are stored in a dictionary, let's assume these are their values. Note that they always come in as strings, even for numeric variables:

```
x, y, z = '5', '6', 'abc'
```

So my question is how I can safely evaluate (i.e. without using `eval()`) the truth of `myStr` in reference to this last line.

What I have done is: First change `myStr` to reflect the data types:

```
import re
delim = "(\>|\<=|\ in )" # Put in group to find later which delimiter is used

def pyRules(s):
    varName = re.split(delim, s)[0]
    rest = "".join(re.split(delim, s)[1:])
    if varName in categoricalVars:
        return varName + rest
    else:
        return "float(" + varName + ")" + rest
# Call:
[pyRules(e) for e in myStr.split(' and ')] 
# Result:
['float(x)>2', 'float(y)<=30', "z in ('def', 'abc')"]
```

Now I can easily do:

```
[eval(pyRules(e)) for e in myStr.split(' and ')]
# Result:
[True, True, True]
```

But I want to avoid this. I tried `ast.literal_eval()` but got the following error:

```
import ast
[ast.literal_eval(pyRules(e)) for e in myStr.split(' and ')]
# Result:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-556-dae16951de03>", line 1, in <module>
    ast.literal_eval(ast.parse(conds[0]))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')

ValueError: malformed string
```

Next, I tried the following approach, which almost gave me the right answer:

```
def pyRules(s):
    varName = re.split(delim, s)[0]
    operation = "".join(re.split(delim, s)[1:])
    if varName in categoricalVars:
        return "'{" + varName + "}'" + operation
    else:
        return "float({" + varName + "})" + operation

rules = [pyRules(e).format(x='5',y='6',z='abc') for e in myStr.split(' and ')] 
# rules is:
['float(5)>2', 'float(6)<=30', "'abc' in ('def', 'abc')"]
```

I can again use the `eval()` on this and get `[True, True, True]` but to avoid it I defined my own inequality checker function:

```
def check(x):
    first, operation, second = re.split(delim, x)
    if operation == ">":
        return first > second
    elif operation == "<=":
        return first <= second
    elif operation == " in ":
        return first in second
# Call:
[check(pyRules(e).format(x='5',y='6',z='abc')) for e in myStr.split(' and ')] 
# Result:
[True, False, True]
```

It is having a hard time evaluating the second item, i.e: `'float(6)<=30'` I also recreated this function using the `operator` module per [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913167/python-pass-inequality-as-string-in-dict-for-evaluation) which is essentially the same thing, and got the same result.

I checked [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), couldn't get it to work (which even looks scary, look at [this!](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py)), and [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) but unfortunately it also uses `eval` frequently, as documented in the hyperlink I provided.

**Question 2:** Is it okay to use `eval` given that I am 100% sure that I don't have any crazy string that can interfere with `os` and erase my disk and other crazy stuff like that?

Note: This is a piece of a big code that I built in Python 2, so Python 2 based answers would be ideal; but I can move to Python 3 if anybody thinks my answer is in that sphere.

Comment: `eval()` is problematic with untrusted strings.  Otherwise, it is just running code.

Comment: Take a look at [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr), it might be of some use.

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch! I will use `eval()` if nothing cool comes up.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thank you! It seems promising at first sight, I'm checking it right now.

Comment: I think it is just OK to use `eval` if you fully trust your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of work, I figured out a way to get `ast.literal_eval()` to work! My logic is to look at the two sides of, say, `x>2`, i.e. `x` and `2`, make sure these are safe by evaluating both with `literal_eval`, and then run it through my `check()` function, which does the evaluation. Same for `z in ('def', 'abc')`: First make sure both `z` and `('def', 'abc')` are safe, then do the actual boolean checking with the `check()` function.

Since I fully trusted my inputs I could've done the easier `eval()` way, but just wanted to be double-cautious. **And wanted to build some code for everybody out there who have security issues (user inputs etc.) and need to safely evaluate logicals.** Hope it helps somebody!

Please see my full code below, any comments/recommendations are welcome.

```
import re
import ast

myStr = "x>2 and y<=30 and z in ('def', 'abc')"
categoricalVars = ('z')
x, y, z = '5', '6', 'abc'
delim = "(\>|\<=|\ in )" # Put in group to find in the func check() which delimiter is used

def pyRules(s):
    """
    Place {} around variable names so that we can str.format() in the func check()
    """
    varName = re.split(delim, s)[0]
    rest = "".join(re.split(delim, s)[1:])
    return "'{" + varName + "}'" + rest

def check(x):
    """
    If operation is > or <= then it is a numeric var, use double literal_eval to
    parse floats e.g. "'5'" (dual quotes) to 5.0. This is equivalent to:
    float(ast.literal_eval(first)). Else it is categorical, just literal_eval once
    """
    first, operation, second = re.split(delim, x)
    if operation == ">":
        return ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(first)) > ast.literal_eval(second)
    elif operation == "<=":
        return ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(first)) <= ast.literal_eval(second)
    elif operation == " in ":
        return ast.literal_eval(first) in ast.literal_eval(second)

# These are my raw rules:
print [pyRules(e) for e in myStr.split(' and ')] 

# These are my processed rules:
print [pyRules(e).format(x='5',y='6',z='abc') for e in myStr.split(' and ')] 

# And these are my final results of logical evaluation:
print [check(pyRules(e).format(x='5',y='6',z='abc')) for e in myStr.split(' and ')]
```

Results of the three result lines:

```
["'{x}'>2", "'{y}'<=30", "'{z}' in ('def', 'abc')"]
["'5'>2", "'6'<=30", "'abc' in ('def', 'abc')"]
[True, True, True]
```

Thanks!